# How do I list all classes contained and inherited by a given class?

Tags: java, eclipse

Given a class, I want to list all classes:

- Which are the super class of current class(all the way to the top of hierarchy).
- Objects of those classes contained in the given class(and its super classes)
  a comprehensive list.

Solution where I don't have to compile the code is desirable. Wondering if there is a solution in eclipse.

Comment: Rght click on class and go to references.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, right click on the name of the class in the code and choose "Open Type Hierarchy" (or press F4). A window will open that displays both of the things you asked for.